# Get data from 2 tables and make a table in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I have two MySQL tables:

```
offers:

  id   |   rid   |    name 
------------------------------
  1    |  1234   |    mary

  2    |  1235   |    john

  3    |  5342   |    liam
```

And

```
geo_in_off:

offer_id   |   geo_id   
------------------------------
   1       |  1234  
   2       |  1235   
   3       |  5342
```

I need to make a table on my website looging like:

```
1(number) | 1234(rid) | name(name) | 1(geo_id)
```

But I got MySQL troubles.

My code is:

```
require('../config.php');
echo "<table class=\"offer-table\">";
echo "<tr><th id=\"off_col_num\">№</th><th id=\"off_col_id\">offer ID</th><th id=\"off_col_name\">Название</th><th id=\"off_col_geo\">Geo</th></tr>";
$i = 1;
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `offers` ORDER BY `rid` JOIN geo_in_off ON geo_in_off.id = offers.id"; 
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()); 

while ($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<tr><td>" . $i . "</td><td>" . $row['rid'] . "</td><td>" . 
    $row['name'] . "</td><td>" .$i . "</td></tr>"  ;
    $i++;
}

echo "</table>";
```

I've got problems with MySQL synaxis and the logic how to get the data from 2 tables and give the result in one "while loop".

So I need to join 2 queries in one:

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `offers` ORDER BY `rid`";
$sql ="SELECT `geo_id` FROM `geo_in_off` WHERE `offer_id` = '$each_offer_id_from_offers'";
```

And optional but not necessary:

```
$sql ="SELECT `name` FROM `geo` WHERE `id` = '$geo_id_got_from_table_geo_in_off'";
```

And get a table where I get the offer id, the offer name and the offer geo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `offers` ORDER BY `rid` JOIN geo_in_off ON geo_in_off.id = offers.id";
```

To

```
$sql ="SELECT * FROM `offers` JOIN `geo_in_off` ON `geo_in_off`.`offer_id` = `offers`.`id` ORDER BY `offers`.`rid`";
```

1) ORDER BY order is wrong in your query

> SELECT column1, column2, ...
>
> FROM table_name
>   ORDER BY column1, column2, ... ASC|DESC;

2) Instead of `geo_in_off.id = offers.id` use `geo_in_off.offer_id = offers.id`

Comment: no. I am getting no errors now but I get only 4 results instead of whole table. And can you tell me pls how to echo the geo_id to my table?

Comment: IT WORKS FINE. but I've got a problem:  1) I get not the whole table of offers - only the one - who has a geo. 2) If the offer has 2 geo_id's so i get a dublicate - but should get 2nd geo in the 1st row. Can u help me pls/

Answer (score 2):

> Try this query, it does help you (full join query)

```
SELECT offers.*, geo_in_off.geo_id FROM offers,
geo_in_off WHERE offers.id=geo_in_off.offer_id
```

Comment: this works fine. BIG THANKS. but how should I get the geo id from the 2nd table in PHP code? And what if geo_id is multiple? And I DID not get the whole table in this query. only 4 results

Comment: Can you help me? I have the last question: how to remove duplicates whow have a view geo_id from the 2nd table? and get the 2nd geo_id in 1 row in a <TD>

Comment: wait for moment

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
$sql = 'SELECT of.id, of.rid, of.name, geo.id 
FROM of.offers 
INNER JOIN of.id = geo.offer_id 
WHERE offer_id = \''.$each_offer_id_from_offers.'\' order by of.rid'
```

Comment: Where I should get the var $each_offer_id_from_offers ?

Comment: You use it in your comments, so I use it. You can replace it for the specific value you want in your where clause.